# Query in MS SQL Server 2014 taking long time in spite of covering index

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2014 hosting multiple applications and trying to run following query:

```
SELECT distinct Col_1,Col_2,Col_3 FROM TABLE WHERE  col_3 LIKE '%criteria%'
```

There is a clustered index on Col_1 and non-clustered index on Col_2 and Col_3.  However, non-clustered index on Col_3 includes another column that is not part of this query.

The total number of rows in the table is 115,000 and rows returned by this query are 1132.

I tried running it five times and following is the time taken for each try

```
1:32,
1:51,
1:52,
1:50,
2:05
```

I checked the number of concurrent connections allowed to the server which is unlimited (0 is specified).

I checked minimum and maximum memory allocated to server is 0 and 4096 MB.

Question: Why a query with small number of rows taking so much time in spite of the fact that indexes have been created for all the columns in query.

Comment: Short answer? Your statement is not SARGable. The reason for that is it can't utilize the covering query because you have the wildcard at the begining of your criteria as well. Might want to read up on this: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server

Comment: Check the query execution to identify if you're missing any indexes or to identify where it is taking time? Mostly, looks like an index issue.

Answer (score 1):

No normal index can help because the index structure cannot assist a `LIKE` query with a leading wildcard.

If you're querying for *words*<sup>1</sup> and its acceptable in your environment, you may be able to turn on [*full text search*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) on `col_3`. Full text indexing can help because it's *word* oriented and is designed to support [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) style querying.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless this is a "keywords" style column in which case it should not be stored like this at all and should instead be remodelled so that each keyword is contained in its own row in some table that *references* the current table under discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

How about if i change the "WHERE" condition to  
CHARINDEX('criteria',column_3) > 0

Do you think it will help ??

Comment: No, the current index you have lists all of the values stored in `col_3` in alphabetical order. It's helpful if you know what the leading characters of the thing you're searching for are, but not for if you're searching for text where the leading characters are unknown. Try this exercise at home - take a dictionary and find all words that have the characters `set` appearing anywhere within them. Does the fact that the dictionary exists and is sorted in alphabetic order actually assist you much with that task?

Comment: Got your point... thank you bro...

However, can you comment on the fact that sometimes the same query return the result set very quickly ... in like 5-15 seconds... and then again go back to same routine of returning the result in more than 1.5 minutes...

what could be the reason for this ??

Comment: @Tiyyob - most like reason for speed up is if most/all pages of the table have stayed in RAM and not been evicted due to other queries.

Comment: @Tiyyob, note that even with a covering index, a full scan will be required because of the leading wildcard. Performance of such a scan will be better with a legacy SQL collation instead of a Windows collation due to less complex comparison rules. Other than collation, not much else can be done except for the suggested full text search.